# gcc error when trying to download mysqlclient

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have been trying to migrate python models into a mysql database. When ever I issue the following command in terminal:

```
(sl_env) Nolans-MBP:student_loans NolanMorrow$ python3 manage.py makemigrations
```

I get

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: mysqlclient 1.3.13 or newer is required; you have 0.9.3.'''
```

At which point I enter

```
(sl_env) Nolans-MBP:student_loans NolanMorrow$ pip3 install mysqlclient
```

and get the following error.

```
Running setup.py install for mysqlclient ... error
```

...

```
ld: library not found for -lssl
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: You can link the specific library with `-L yourlibrary`

Comment: Did you install `python3-dev` or `python3-devel`?

Comment: Can you be more specific on how i link the library using that command? I'm extremely new. Not even sure what a library is.